# Button automatically activating

Tags: autohotkey

I'm not quite sure why, but whenever I run the ahk file the button automatically activates. (I put the `GuiClose: ExitApp` so that it doesn't infinitely refresh). Also, is there a better way to do this?

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, force
ontop = 1
Gui, -Caption

Gui, Font,cPurple s10, Arial Bold
Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y0 gUImove, bg-1.jpg
Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y40, bg-1.jpg
If ontop = 1
{
    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
}

Gui, Add, Text, x190 y0 +BackgroundTrans,test
Gui, Add, Button, x100 y200 w120 h40 , disableOnTop

Gui, Show, w500 h340

TrayTip , Title, test, 20
UImove: 
GuiClose:
ExitApp
disableOnTop:
{
    If ontop = 0
    {
        ontop = 1
        Reload
        Sleep 5000
        Return 
    }
    Else If ontop = 1
    {
        ontop = 1
        Reload
        Sleep 5000
        Return
    }
}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code following the `disableOnTop` label to run when clicking the GUI button, you need to put its name in the options of the button following a letter "g", like so:

`Gui, Add, Button, x100 y200 w120 h40 gdisableOnTop , Click me`

For proper functionality, you'll also need to put a `Return` after `Gui, Show`.

Note that variables are not saved when you reload. Also, note that the `Sleep 5000` and `Return` are after `Reload`, which means it won't be executed. (Unless it can't reload, such as if there is a syntax error.)

I'm surprised that it's running your button code at all; it looks like it should run into `ExitApp` and all you'd see is a brief flash of the GUI before it exits.